# SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
import discord.ext
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import os
import schedule
client = discord.Client()


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="")

channel_id = 927272717227528262

channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)

@tasks.loop(seconds=1.0)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
def job2():
    await message.channel.send("message")

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job2)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(0)


keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Every time I run it I get :

```
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

I am also having the issue where message is undefined the definition of `job2` even though it was just defined in the line above.

Comment: You never await inside of the async function. You can't call it in job2() later. It has to be in the async def

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.loop). Async functions aren't really supported by `schedule`.

In fact, your bot can never run because your `schedule.run_pending()` in the infinite loop will never end.

In order to keep your `message` there you'll need to put it in a global of some type.

```py
the_message = None

@tasks.loop(seconds=1.0)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global the_message
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    the_message = message

async def job2():
    if the_message is None:
        return
    await the_message.channel.send("message")

@tasks.loop(seconds=10.0)  # you can do other things like `minutes=5` or `hours=1.75`
async def my_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    await job2()

my_task.start()

# then the bot runs fine after
keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Be careful that this might run before your client is not ready and initializing. You may also want to check [`wait_until_ready`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_until_ready#discord.Client.wait_until_ready) if you're going to do anything with the API, like in your case. You can also find other examples [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#recipes).

Comment: message not defined inside job2

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński that’s in the code the OP gave, I’m not sure if that’s a global or a `get_channel/message/guild` thing.

Comment: *”I am also having the issue where message is undefined the definition of job2 even though it was just defined in the line above.”*

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Does need more clarification though, I suspect they want the last message sent, which I guess make it a global then. I’ll update this once I’m available.

Answer (score 0):

1. `await` is used in asynchronous functions to wait for the function to do its thing. However, you have used it in a synchronous function (`def job2`)
2. `message` is not a variable. `message` is the parameter of the `on_message` function. A parameter can only be used in the function it is provided to.

Hope this answered your question.